# customize buttons

Tags: android, button

can anyone tell me what are these buttons? used at the top of colornote app, and how to do like them
you can see them here in the third screenshot:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5zb2NpYWxubW9iaWxlLmRpY3RhcHBzLm5vdGVwYWQuY29sb3Iubm90ZSJd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [android-actionbar](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar). It's not exactly the same, but similar.

Comment: thank you and @AngeloS , that is the best kind of buttons to me

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the action bar.  Here are the Android dev docs on it :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html